# Expand text in line

Tags: html

I have been trying to figure out a way to expand text (similar to collapsible section) in a sentence.   I want to be able to wright a sentence and have some of the words clickable to expand and show more text.   All of they ways I have found create a section below the clicked word or button that expands and contracts.   Is there a way to do this?

Example:
Here are a few words on my thought about the movie **Deadpool**

*click on Deadpool*

Here are a few words on my thought about the movie **Deadpool** it was so well shot and a movie I just can't wait to see again.

Comment: What is your actual question? Have you attempted anything? You've asked *"Is there a way to do this?"* immediately after a sentence that starts with *"All of the ways I have found..."*, so I have to imagine that you already know that there are *plenty* of ways to do this. Please specify what you're actually asking, or if you have code, please include it.

Comment: Yes, sorry.   I have found several ways to create an expandable drop down but I have not been able to find any examples of it just expanding the sentence into a paragraph.  Probably due to my bad googling.    I can't think of a proper way to search for an example let alone the code to create my own.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for HTML5's `<details>` tag:

```css
details,
details[open],
summary {
  display: inline;
}

summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
Here are a few words on my thought about the movie <details><summary>Deadpool</summary> it was so well shot and a movie I just can't wait to see again.</details>
```

Comment: Hey this is awesome.   Do you know if there is a way to keep it from dropping down to a new line?

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found is [StretchText](https://github.com/BradNeuberg/stretchtext.js), implemented with js.

If you're open to other displays, your problem could be solved with
[popup](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip)
or `toggle text`, also on w3schools.

FWIW, it might be possible to hack the css of `details` (the other answer).